# What is the reason for (general logic) of the PEBOOT BIOS boot table entry (or EUFI partion) on a DELL machine (BIOS setup screen)?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, uefi, dell-xps

The BIOS setup page 'boot systems' for my *Dell XPS 9320, Ubuntu variation*, is driving me crazy.  I disable entries for "ubuntu" and PEBOOT (uncheck the boxes) and exit setup.  It looks like I'm getting 2 boots, the first one is very quick; just a Dell flash screen for a second.  Another boot automatically occurs, and I'm looking at my Ubuntu system staring up.

Remember I disabled the "Ubuntu" entry in the table.  Intercepting the ubuntu (2nd) boot and restarting BIOS setup shows an altered table, as it something is trying "help" or "protect" me from not getting Ubuntu started, and activating a UBUNTU entry -- **even adding it** when totally delete the entry.

(When I force booting the PEBOOT partition (by disabling all other entries), the DELL support/recovery program starts up, and when it exits table has been reset to a factory default with an entry for ubuntu.)

I suspect that either the PEBOOT partition (one some other "hidden" one) is resetting the table adding ubuntu and fallback entries.

What's going on, and why won't {*name of program*} leave my settings alone???

Comment: We cannot change the way your BIOS works, unfortunately. (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: @harrymc I'm not asking YOU to change my BIOS.  Only DELL does bios changes.   But there is no reason why someone can't describe what happens today, as is.

Comment: Your question is scattered and disconnected. It is difficult to tell what is going on due to how you've written your question. I strongly recommend that you rewrite the question removing the asides and focusing on a strict and focused description of the problem, the research you've done, what you've tried, and how it has failed.

Answer (score 0):

UEFI booting is file-based. Normal (i.e. except those leads you to firmware setting or so) boot entries each refers to a EFI executable in a supported filesystem. (UEFI spec only mandates the FAT-family to be supported; but do note that it does not forbid other types to be supported as well.)

There are two ways in which the boot entries are created:

1. Statically created upon e.g. bootloader installation to point to an executable at an arbitrary location
2. Dynamically created for executable under the fallback path (e.g. `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI`) found on each enumerated filesystem upon boot.

I don't know whether the UEFI spec mandates entries of the second type to be gone by the next boot, or whether they would be written to the NVRAM (i.e. where UEFI store persistent states / data) in most implementation, but I suppose it makes sense for them to be transient as the type/approach is mainly for removable drives.

I also don't know if the UEFI spec mandates or recommends the type of entries to be always ordered before the static ones, but my guess is it doesn't since whether the behavior is desirable totally depends on the given scenario or preference of the user. As a result / Therefore, the ordering heuristics are likely vendor-specific.

One thing you might try to do is to have the EFI executable of the bootloader placed at path different from the fallback one (and the Windows one) and create a static entry for it. It can be created with e.g. `efibootmgr` in Linux or a EFI shell. Some firmware have a setting page for you to do that as well. (Better make sure you remove the file at the fallback path since some older / more broken firmware don't like the same filesystem having both types of entries, although that would break "portability" of the drive.) If your firmware does not remove but merely ignore "invalid" static entries upon boot, you may be able to get your desired behavior/order with this trick. (But certainly, it would at best require an entry to be created for each USB drive you'd want to boot, and you might even need luck for it to not get you into other issues.)

For the record, some firmware vendor (notably Pheonix) have approach that is different from the more "reference" one (i.e. EDK2 / AMI style). You may notice that implementation from such vendor do it in a per-drive/per-drive-type approach, that is, it will only enumerate the first supported filesystem on each internal (SATA/NVMe) drive and e.g. the first USB drive. Such implementations usually have some predefined entries which will map to one of the drives of the corresponding type dynamically and won't come and go from the boot ordering. However, as I implied, such approach is AFAIK is not mentioned at all in the UEFI spec, but designed by the vendor itself to mimick a boot order/menu in the legacy, but less "strange", style.

---

While I mentioned that UEFI booting is file-based, IIRC the boot entries themselves do have data regarding the "device path" of the drive/partition of where the corresponding filesystem / executable resides. It includes like pci bus no, scsi lun, and partition number in addition to the partition UUID. I don't remember if only the dynamic/transient entries have the "hardware info" though. I point this out because these extra info (including the partition UUID) is how each fallback path refers to executable in  different filesystems, and why you'll need to create static entry for "each" USB drive if you want to try my suggested workaround. (And now you may notice the workaround in turn which can make the "upper" workaround apply on "every" USB drive you plug in: same port, same partition UUID, etc.)

---

I don't think anyone without hands-on experience with (the specific) Dell machine (or actually, the source code of its firmware) could tell exactly why the disablement of boot entries gets forgotten, but most likely it's nothing but a bug (e.g. all disablement get reset whenever a dynamic entry is created/removed, something like that).

Comment: I think you're right about no answer being available short of the developer...